# Declaring type for this in function body

Tags: typescript

In the typescript documentation the following example is given on how to use **type** for *this* usage inside a callback function. Can someone please help me to understand how the callback will work here?

```
interface DB {
  filterUsers(filter: (this: User) => boolean): User[];
}
 
const db = getDB();
const admins = db.filterUsers(function (this: User) {
  return this.admin;
});
```

Comment: It's just a type annotation; it will be compiled to `function () { return this.admin; }`. The type annotation tells the compiler that the function will be bound to an instance of `User` before being called.

Comment: *"Can someone please help me to understand how the callback will work here?"* Can you be more specific about what part you don't understand?

Comment: How the function will bound to an User instance here ?

Comment: filterUsers run  your callback function with user parameter and if your user matches the condition it will added to result. In second code you give just admin condition. if user is admin it will added to admins result

Comment: @BarışCanYılmaz - Not just as a simple parameter, as `this`, which is quite different.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For methods and traditional functions (*not* arrow functions), `this` is effectively a read-only parameter whose value is passed to the function by the code calling it. ([More here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3127429/how-does-the-this-keyword-work).) When the function's code runs, `this` is whatever the caller set it to (explicitly or implicitly).

The `this` pseudo-parameter in TypeScript lets you tell TypeScript what type `this` will have when the function is called. So the `DB` interface's `filterUsers` method is defined saying that `this` will refer to a `User` object when the callback is called.

You don't have to repeat it when you write the callback (though you can), TypeScript will infer it from the `DB` interface's definition:

```
const db = getDB();
const admins = db.filterUsers(function() {
  return this.admin;
  //     ^? −−−−− here, `this` has the type `User`
});
```

---

In a comment you've asked:

> How the function will bound to an `User` instance here ?

Code in `filterUsers` will ensure that when it calls the callback, it does so with `this` set to a user. It might do that with either [`Function.prototype.call`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call) or [`Function.prototype.apply`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply):

```
// Notional (not literal!) code for a `filterUsers` method:
filterUsers(callback: (this: User) => boolean): User[] {
    const filtered = this.users.filter(user => callback.call(user));
    //                                                 ^^^^^   ^
    //                                                         |
    //                          the value to use as `this` −−−−+
    return filtered;
}
```

`.call` and `.apply` allow you to *explicitly* state what `this` should be when calling a function.

---

It's probably worth noting that this would be an unfortunate way for `DB`'s `filterUsers` to be defined. It would be much more convenient for users of the interface if the user were passed as a simple parameter (as with `Array.prototype.filter` and such), not as `this`. But it's a synthetic example in the documentation for explaining this syntax.